# Node.js child_process module not working with long bat code as single liner code

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, cmd, child-process

I worked now a time successfully with child_process to exec small single liner code or just to exec a .bat file. But I´am tired to always create extra .bat files for my projects.Please notice that I work only on localhost on my PC so I don´t need a server side solution. Is there a way to use .bat like this below or any other kind of bats that include stuff like for loops as single liner in node.js?:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
echo Local date is [%ldt%]
pause
```

The .bat will generate the current data and it worked fine when you open it via .bat file :)

Now I tried this:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')

exec('@echo off & for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if \'.%%i.\'==\'.LocalDateTime.\' set ldt=%%j & set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6% & echo Local date is [%ldt%]', (err, stdout, stderr) => {

  if ( stderr || err ) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr + '\nerr: ' + err)
  } 
  else{
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout)
  } 

})
```

I thought `&&` will not work here so I used `&` .. I also escaped `\'`

But I get error:

```
"%%i" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden
```

In english should be something like:

```
"%%i" cannot be processed syntactically
```

Sorry if I translate it bad :(

Anybody an idea to write stuff like complex for loops etc. as single liner with `&` operators? Thank you for all help :)

Comment: Something like this could help. : https://github.com/bitsofinfo/stateful-process-command-proxy

Comment: I think that exec `wmic os get ...` and parse stdout by Node is more readable than lousy `bat` shell.

Comment: This looks really complex and I need it as small as possible. Also I use node.js as localhost on my pc not on server. Can you tell me please how you would open a sample bat with this plugin?

Comment: @Aikon Mogwai yeha this is a cool short way for get the date thank you! But I need a solution for all kind of bats.